# OpenStreetMap data OSMOSIS and MySQL - make faster?

Tags: openstreetmap, mysql, osmosis

How can I make dumping .osm data into a MySQL database faster using Osmosis? Currently 3 hours so far for the USA file but MySQL is only using 10-15 percent CPU, 10 percent RAM and HD is negligible (32gb RAM, i7 12700 and M.2 4.0 drive). Something in my.ini that I need to adjust or just the limitations of osmosis and MySQL? Using Win 11 and Xampp.

Answer (score 1):

Osmosis can be used to load OSM data into an apidb schema database. This database is particularly designed for the OSM API, which, many years in the past, used to use MySQL. You almost certainly want to use osm2pgsql, imposm, or other software to load a database suitable for rendering, analysis and other usage of OSM data.

If you do want an apidb database, you need to use PostgreSQL. The MySQL tasks in osmosis do not support 0.6, the current API and data model.

When loading into an apidb, I would expect loading all of the US to take about a week.